# Rename files in same path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write a method that will rename all .new file extensions to a new name 
I have seen similar post but nothing as specific as what i am asking.

my code needs to rename the files in the directory it is in.  since the method is searching multiple directories. the code I have written renames the files in the root directory.

this function will be ran on multiple directories so using `pathname = "/path/to/app/"` will not work for me.  here is the code:

```
dotNewFiles = File.join("**", "*.new") 

Dir.glob(dotNewFiles).each do |f|
  filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))

  #keep it commented until it works 
  #File.rename(f, filename)

  print "Renamed File from:\t"
  printf "%-50s %s\n", f, "to".upcase + "\t" + filename
end
```

my output looks like this:

```
Renamed File from:  app/assets/javascripts/application.js.new   TO   application.js

 Renamed File from:  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.new   TO   application.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dir.glob('**/*.new').each do |f|
  filename = File.expand_path('../' + File.basename(f, File.extname(f)), f)
  # or
  # filename = f.sub(/\.new$/, '')

  File.rename(f, filename)

  print "Renamed File from:\t"
  printf "%-50s %s\n", f, "to".upcase + "\t" + filename
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the directory into account, e.g.:

```
Dir.glob(dotNewFiles).each do |f|
  dirname, basename = File.split(f)           # split filename into directory and basename
  basename = File.basename(basename, ".new")  # change basename
  filename = File.join(dirname, basename)     # join directory and new basename
  File.rename(f, filename)
end
```